# Print / view all variables whilst a script is running in python

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, error-handling

I'm looking for a way to view all of the variables during running so I can debug easier.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work how I want it to:

```
import inspect

a = False
b = ""
c = "test"
d = {}
e = []
f = ["Test", "Test"]
g = ("One", "1", "Two", "2")


h = inspect.currentframe()
print h.f_locals
```

Ideally I want it to print it similar to below or just let me see what variable has what data

```
a
False

b
""

c
test

d
{}

e
[]

f
test, test

g
One, 1, Two, 2
```

This way I can see the variables and their data easily...

In VBA it's easy because you have a window with all variables.

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: IPython or `pdb` may be worth looking into.

Comment: `pprint.pprint(locals())` can give you a more nicely-formatted display of your local variable dict, or you can write a function that iterates over it and prints it how you want. I'll leave the answers to people with more knowledge of the tools available, though.

Comment: @user2357112

I've had a look into iPython but I'm still trying to work out how to use it :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `vars()`:

```
a = False
b = ""
c = "test"
d = {}
e = []
f = ["Test", "Test"]
g = ("One", "1", "Two", "2")
for k, v in vars().items():
    if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__')):
        print k,'--',v
```

**Output:**

```
a -- False
c -- test
b -- 
e -- []
d -- {}
g -- ('One', '1', 'Two', '2')
f -- ['Test', 'Test']
```

Help on `vars`:

```
>>> print vars.__doc__
vars([object]) -> dictionary

Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
```

Comment: Works nice, thanks Upvote given :)

Chosen your answer. Thank you ever so much :)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of non-stdlib things that I use frequently:

First, one of ipython's more useful magic functions: `%whos`

```
In [21]: a = 'hi'
    ...: bob = list()
    ...: 

In [22]: %whos
Variable   Type    Data/Info
----------------------------
a          str     hi
bob        list    n=0
```

`%who` just lists the vars without giving info on the contents.

Second, [q](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/q).  You can do more powerful inline debugging and even open an interactive prompt at an arbitrary point in your code.

```
In [1]: def stuff():
   ...:     a = 'hi'
   ...:     b = 'whatever'
   ...:     c = [1,2,3]
   ...:     import q; q.d()
   ...:     return a,b
   ...: 

In [2]: stuff()
Python console opened by q.d() in stuff
>>>
```

[Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OL3De8BAhME&t=25m13s) an amusing video (lightning talk) of the author talking about q if anyone is interested.

Comment: I've had a look into iPython but really quite struggling to convert my huge mess of code into it and to get it work. I'm sure my code can be improved massively but I'm still learning so it's slow and tough

Answer (score 2):

```
import inspect
import copy

# Store pre-existing attributes, which aren't generated by you.
uninteresting_keys = inspect.currentframe().f_locals.keys()
uninteresting_keys.append('uninteresting_keys')

a = False
b = ""
c = "test"
d = {}
e = []
f = ["Test", "Test"]
g = ("One", "1", "Two", "2")

# Make a copy, otherwise f_locals changes size during the for loops, which causes an error.
locals = copy.copy(inspect.currentframe().f_locals)
for key in locals:
#   if the attribute is not in our list of preexisting attributes, print it out with its` value:
    if key not in uninteresting_keys:
        print key
        print locals[key]
        print
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `inspect`, you could also iterate through .f_locals.items()

```
h = inspect.currentframe()
for var, data in h.f_locals.items():
    print "Var {0} : {1}".format(var, data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you want is all in what you got back from `f_locals`. It's just a matter of formatting and printing it. You may also want to omit `__special__` names. You can trivially write a function to do this:

```
import inspect

def print_locals(frame=None):
    frame = frame or inspect.currentframe().f_back 
    locs = frame.f_locals
    spec = "%" + str(max(len(n) for n in locs)) + "s"
    for name in sorted(locs, key=str.lower):
       if not (name.startswith("__") and name.endswith("__")):
           print spec % name, "=", repr(locs[name])
```

You can call this function with no arguments whenever you want a dump of the current context, or you may easily write a signal handler that calls it when you press `^C`:

```
import signal

def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print_locals(frame)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,sigint_handler)
```